# Server 2008 migration from 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is it possilbe to migrate from 2003 Server-Standard 32-bit to a 2008 Server-Standard 64-bit. I'm not able to run the ADPREP from the 2008 disk without error.

Comment: What specifically are you migrating? Files, Active Directory, SQL Server, Exchange, <other random LOB app>?

Comment: What error, specifically, do you get?  If running from your Server 2003 machine, be sure to [use the 32-bit version](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464018%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_R2Adprep) `Adprep32.exe` on the 2008 DVD.

Comment: Can you please also clarify if you're trying to upgrade on the same box, or migrate to another?

Answer (score 4):

Windows will not upgrade from 32-bit to 64-bit, doesn't matter what version/edition.

You can run adprep32 with the Server 2008 (or R2) LDIFs and update the schema. Then install a 2008 Server somewhere, add AD, migrate the FSMO Roles, and decommission the original server.

Answer (score 0):

Chris is right. Regardless of which tools you are trying to run, it won't matter in the end. 32bit OS to 64bit OS simply isn't possible.